# Check if user is sysop

Tags: php, mediawiki

How to check if user have sysop or other permission (in file `LocalSettings.php` or extension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'ifUserSysop';
function ifUserSysop() {

    global $wgUser;

    if (in_array("sysop", $wgUser->getEffectiveGroups())) {
        // if sysop
    }

    if($wgUser->isLoggedIn()) {
        // is logged in
    }

    return true;

}
```

Full contents of `$wgUser->getEffectiveGroups()` for sysop:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bureaucrat
    [1] => editor
    [2] => sysop
    [3] => *
    [4] => user
)
```

For user:

```
Array
(
    [0] => *
    [1] => user
)
```

For anon:

```
Array
(
    [0] => *
)
```

More intresting things (`$wgUser->isAnon(), isLoggedIn(), isBlocked()`) available [here](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/User.php?view=markup#l2318)

Comment: Note that ParserFirstCallInit should be used only if you're extending the parser, otherwise other appropriate hooks or $wgExtensionFunctions should be used.