# How to check if user is Sysop using Php in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to add a div to my sidebar and I only want this block to show to administrators. How can I check if a user is an administrator in php? I am trying to add this to myskin.php file and dont know how to do it. I have been using something like this to check if a user is logged in,

```
<?php if($this->data['loggedin']) { ?>
```

Is there anything similar to that to check if that user is a sysop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the answer by *blackops_programmer* checks whether the user can protect pages. Per default, that would be sysops, but the permission can be assigned or removed from any group.

If what you want to do depends on the right to protect pages, then checking the permission is the correct way (except you should use $this->getUser(), not $wgUser). 
However, if you really want to check for the sysop group, use this:

```
if ( in_array( 'sysop', $this->getUser()->getEffectiveGroups() ) {
  echo 'Hello People';
}
```

Comment: +1. It would also be possible to make up a new user right for whatever it is you want to allow sysops to do, assign that right to the sysop group and then check for it using `$this->getUser()->isAllowed()`.

Comment: hi brightbyte, thats perfect and its make more sense to use your method for me. I am trying to add that inside my base template and I am getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyCustomTemplate::getUser() in localhost\wiki\skins\muycustomtemplate\MyCustomTemplate.skin.php on line 331

Comment: it works when I have $wgUser instead of getUser() inside my base template but shows "Fatal error: Call to undefined method" when I use getUser(). Any reason why you recommended not to use $wgUser? Also I believe the getUser() isint working inside the html section in my base template is maybe I might need to define the method for getUser() to work and dont know how to do that...

Comment: Hi brightbyte, It works now. I just need to add getSkin() in order for it to work. Also there is just a small typo with 1 less closing bracket in your code. Thats okay, its a simple typo. Anyhow, the code that works for me now looks like this: 

if ( in_array( 'sysop', $this->getSkin()->getUser()->getEffectiveGroups() ) ) {
     // if sysop
}

That is an excellent method and I am going to use this instead of using if($wgUser->isAllowed('protect')) method. If you are able to tell me the reason for why not to use $wgUser will be great. Thank you heaps for your solution! Its brilliant! :)

Comment: Glad I could help, and sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I added the following to my skin template to add special conditions for sysops and non sysops:

```
     <?php 

      global $wgUser;

      if($wgUser->isAllowed('protect')) {
         // if sysop
            echo 'Hello People';
        }

        else {
            echo 'Yo';
        }
      ?>
```

I got the idea from here: [Check if user is sysop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027076/check-if-user-is-sysop)

If there is a better way to do this, please do let me know. But so far, the above seems to work when I added that code to the basetemplate of my skin.

Comment: This doesn't really check the user group. If you want the user group, see the answer I just added.